# Unable to Mock EntityManager Criteria API

Tags: java, spring-boot, unit-testing, junit, junit5

I want to write the junit for EntityManager but unable to mock the EntityManager. My service class method listed below:

```
@PersistenceContext
private EntityManager em;

public List<Items> getItems() {
    Order order = Order.desc("ASC");
    Criteria crit = em.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Items.class);
    Criteria critRowCount = em.unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Items.class);
    crit.add(Restrictions.eq("createdBy", "John"));
    critRowCount.add(Restrictions.eq("createdBy", "John"));

    crit.setFirstResult((pageNo - 1) * pageSize);
    crit.setMaxResults(pageSize);
    crit.addOrder(order);
    List<Items> items = crit.list();
    critRowCount.add(Restrictions.sqlRestriction("Query"));

    critRowCount.setProjection(Projections.rowCount()).uniqueResult();
    return items;
}
```

I used in my tast case:

```
@MockBean
private EntityManager em;
```

and when I called below method in service

```
List<Items> items = crit.list();
```

This will hit DB. Please halp me to resolve the problem.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why the mocking does not work (from what you present here, I'd say it should work). But I would like to suggest another approach. I suppose the `getItems()` method resides in some kind of Repository or DAO or whatever you call this kind of thing. For unit-tests I would usually mock them. If I would want to test `getItems()`, I would actually try to test it through the database (e.g. via [testcontainers](https://www.testcontainers.org/)) in an integration test, because this rather close to the database anyway.

In your concrete case I would probably not even try to test `getItems()`, since it only seems to contain some plumbing code.

As a rule of thumb: It is usually not a good idea to mock what you do not own.

Comment: Thanks for clarification. getItems() is in service and I want to mock em.unwrap(Session.class) so we can return custom Criteria  object. Something Like:
doReturn(criteria).when(em).unwrap(Session.class).createCriteria(Items.class);